# Embed metadata fields in Word files using content type hub publishing

Tags: content-type, dip

I have a problem where I want to set a document template for a custom content type that's published using the content type hub.

This document template need to include metadata fields of the content type, not only in the document information panel (DIP) but also in the document itself.

Any idea how to get this done in SharePoint 2013 on premise?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Davy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your document template is for a docx file, look into leveraging Word's Quick Parts to accomplish your goal. [This article](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-Manage-Metadata-in-your-Office-Document.aspx) walks through the necessary steps very clearly.